# HTML5 - Subelements of and object

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I got following problem. I'm implementing some king of editor for some templates. The main functionality of that editor is to drag some rectangles (which are representing some tables) to new positions and save it.

Each rectangle has it name. And I want to display rectangle with text name inside and then drag that rectangle with text inside.

Is such object groups are possible without any tricky workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like fabric.js is exactly what you need:
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

You can see some demos and feel how it can suit you:
http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/demos/index.html